# The link doesn't work inside a retractable side menu. Can someone help me?

Tags: html, css

When I click on link, the list simply closes and the link doesn't work.

The correct way would be when I clicked in a item list, the list expanded and showed it respective links. So I could click on a link and to be redirect to another page, but when I click on link, the list simply closes.

CSS CODE:

```css
*:focus {
  outline:none
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.menu-sanfona {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:#eee;
  margin: 10px;
}
.menu-sanfona span {
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}

.menu-sanfona > li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu-sanfona > li :hover {
    background: #ddd;
  }
.menu-sanfona li ul {
    background:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
}

.menu-sanfona li:focus ul {
    display:block;
}

HTML CODE:
```

```html
<ul class="menu-sanfona">
                <li tabindex="0"> <span class="item">Programas</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="#">Programas</a></span></li>
                        <li><span>Disciplinas</span></li>
                        <li><span>Turmas</span></li>
                        <li><span>Informações</span></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li tabindex="1"> <span class="item">Pessoas</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Discentes</span></li>
                        <li><span>Docentes</span></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li tabindex="2"> <span class="item">Comunicação</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Requerimentos</span></li>
                        <li><span>Mensagens</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have not mentioned the new page to be redirected in your link `<a href="#">Programas</a>` Adding a # will remain at the same page.

Comment: The list is only shown when the container has `:focus`, but if you click on a link, where does the `:focus` go? Try adding `.menu-sanfona ul:hover {display:block}` to ensure the sublist stays visible.

Comment: @Pat I know, but would appear "#" in URL, and this is not happening...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I did that you said, and the problem keeps.. I understood what you explained, but I don't know how I solve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add this to your **CSS**:

```
.menu-sanfona li ul:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

[My Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/5bqL49t5/)